# App Engine GWT code not being executed at the right time

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I have an App Engine GWT app. In my client code, I'm getting the logged in users email, and want to display it. I get the users email by a request to the server.

The problem is that the getUserEmail() method is being executed **after** the onModuleLoad() method has been executed, so that the userEmail-String will turn up as null where i want to display it. I have checked that the getUserEmail()-method actually returns the correct piece of info, my problem, as mentioned, is **when** i get the info i want. Can anyone point me anywhere on why this happens and how to fix this?

```
public String userEmail;

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
        getUserEmail();
        HTML mHTML = new HTML();
        mHTML.setHTML("<HTML><BODY> Logged in as " + userEmail + "</BODY></HTML>");
        RootPanel.get().add(mHTML);
}

public void getUserEmail(){

    requestFactory.getUserEmailRequest().getUserEmail().fire(
        new Receiver<String>()  {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        userEmail = result; 
                    }
                }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method getUserEmail() is [Asynchronous Method Call](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideGettingUsedToAsyncCalls). 
If you want to execute code after callBack then you should write it in the inner class :

```
public void getUserEmail(){

requestFactory.getUserEmailRequest().getUserEmail().fire(
    new Receiver<String>()  {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    userEmail = result; 

                    HTML mHTML = new HTML();
                    mHTML.setHTML("<HTML><BODY> Logged in as " + userEmail + "</BODY></HTML>");
                    RootPanel.get().add(mHTML);
                }
            }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i have done, but is there anyway to make the getUserEmail() synchronous?

Comment: No. In GWT there is no other choice. You can declare UI outside inner classes. But code mHTML.setHTML(result); must be inside.